# Refering a flowchart in Latex

Tags: latex

I made a flowchart in Latex. Now I wnat to refer this flow chart in a sentence, like "As shown in fig. (1)" where fig. 1 is flow chart. However when i am using \ref(flowchart), then instead of refering to folowchart, it is refering to section no. as "As shown in fig. (section no. 1)". How to fix it?

Comment: It would help to see how you defined `flowchart`.

Comment: My crystal ball says: a `label` command will use the last "anchor" seen, if you will. Commands that create anchors are most notably `\section` et al. and `\caption`. The figure and table environments do _not_ create anchors by themselves. (In short: "label _after_ caption, not before")

Comment: Bravo. Label after caption worked. Many thanks